# Visual Studio 2017 No Background in Code Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2017

My background in the code editor in visual studio 2017 is transparent. Does anyone know how I can fix that?

Here is a picture: [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Try to change the theme. `Tools\Options` and in the search box write down `theme`.

Comment: Try to close and reopen VS, this happens if something in your graphics card driver goes wrong

Comment: Both solutions aren't working :(

Comment: If the answer solve your problem don't forget to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the colors are unconfigured. Apparently you tried to install a theme that didn't work or something.

1) Try resetting the visual studio settings.
Tools> Import and export settings> Reset all settings> check "yes, save my current settings"> Finish

2) Close and open Visual Studio.

If that doesn't work, install a new theme: https://studiostyl.es/
and repeat the 2 step.